# Use Eloquent to attach array to query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a **USER** table, an **ITEMS** table, and a **LIKES** table. I'm randomly taking 9 items from the Items table (which is named 'categories') and I want to get an array of users which liked that item. I'm returning a JSON response so I can't use laravel's ORM relationships as far as I know. I want to be able to look through the results (with javascript) like so:

```
foreach item
     item->price
     ....
     foreach user
     (this is how i wish to look through the users with js)
     endforeach
endforeach
{{--Im trying to get an output that looks like so--}}
0: {
   cost: 409
   views: 0
   ...
   user_like_id: {1,5,2,4,5}
}
```

EDIT: This is what I would like to attach the array to...

```
$likes = Category::orderByRaw("RAND()")
             ->leftJoin('likes', 'likes.item_id', '=', 'categories.id')
             ->take(9)
             ->get();
```

I'm relatively new to programming so please dont downnrate this question

Comment: You CAN use ORM here.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek if you say that please tell him how he can achieve that. With eloquent you can call the ```->toJson()``` method on you're result. This converts the output to json.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please show me an example? I edited my question and added the existing code I have. @arjan

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides in ways to make json from objects. The first and simplest is the eloquent `toJson()` method:

```
$likes = Category::orderByRaw("RAND()")
             ->leftJoin('likes', 'likes.item_id', '=', 'categories.id')
             ->take(9)
             ->get()
             ->toJson();
```

`$likes` is now json.

Second method:
If you return a model from a controller or a routecallback function, laravel returns it as json. So:

```
class MyController extends Controller{
    public function getIndex(){
       return Category::orderByRaw("RAND()")
             ->leftJoin('likes', 'likes.item_id', '=', 'categories.id')
             ->take(9)
             ->get();
    }
}
```

This example returns a json response which is quite usefull!

Answer (score 0):

I actually got exactly what I wanted with this:

```
$likes = Category::orderByRaw("RAND()")
                  ->take(9)
                  ->with(array('getLikes' => function($query)
                  {    
                      $query->with('getUser');
                  }))
                  ->get();
```

Works exactly how I want ito :) thanks for the suggestion tho